CI/CD-script on gitlab stopping after first job
For one of my projects I tried to set up a CI/CD-pipeline on gitlab, with the following pipeline script:
# This file is a template, and might need editing before it works on your project.
# To contribute improvements to CI/CD templates, please follow the Development guide at:
# https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/development/cicd/templates.html
# This specific template is located at:
# https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Python.gitlab-ci.yml

# Official language image. Look for the different tagged releases at:
# https://hub.docker.com/r/library/python/tags/
image: python:3.11.8

# Change pip's cache directory to be inside the project directory since we can
# only cache local items.
variables:
  PIP_CACHE_DIR: "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.cache/pip"

# Pip's cache doesn't store the python packages
# https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/caching/
#
# If you want to also cache the installed packages, you have to install
# them in a virtualenv and cache it as well.
cache:
  paths:
    - .cache/pip
    - venv/

before_script:
  - apt-get update && apt-get install ffmpeg libsm6 libxext6 libegl-dev  -y
  - python --version # For debugging
  - pip install poetry
  - cd ./project_dir
  - poetry install --with dev
  - source `poetry env info --path`/bin/activate

stages:
  - test
  - wheel_build
  - doc_build
  - release

test_job:
  image: "python:$VERSION"
  stage: test
  script:
    - ls -R
    - poetry run pytest ./tests/ --junitxml=report.xml
    - ls -R
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - VERSION: ["3.9", "3.11.8"] #["3.9", "3.10", "3.11.8", "3.12"]
  artifacts:
    when: always
    reports:
      junit: /builds/report.xml

wheel_build_job:
  stage: wheel_build
  needs: [test_job]
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
  script:
    - ls -R
    - poetry build
    - ls -R
    - pwd
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - /builds/dist/*.whl

doc_build_job:
  stage: doc_build
  needs: [test_job]
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
  script:
    - cd docs
    - poetry run sphinx-apidoc -o ./source/ ../test_code/
    - poetry run sphinx-build -M html ./source/ ./build/
    - mv build/html/ ../public/
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - /builds/public

release_job:
  stage: release
  needs: [wheel_build_job]
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli:latest
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG # Run this job when a tag is created
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
  script:
    - echo "running release_job"
  release: # See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#release for available properties
    tag_name: "$CI_COMMIT_TAG"
    description: "$CI_COMMIT_TAG"

Everything works fine initially, and each time I push both testing jobs are executed, but even when merging on main (i.e. when $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH is true) no further steps are executed. I assume that it is due to executing the job before merging, however, if I start the job manually on master, it still only executes the test jobs, nothing else.
What exactly should I change here to be able to run all jobs after merging to master?

I think the reason it isn’t working is because one of the variables you are using ($CI_COMIT_BRANCH) is not defined on a merge pipeline, so is not equal to the default branch. $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
From gitlabs documentation:

The commit branch name. Available in branch pipelines, including
pipelines for the default branch. Not available in merge request
pipelines or tag pipelines.

I think you’ve identified the correct issue and I would try using some different rules with some other predefined variables.
Or you could make the jobs run only when the commit branch is == master for jobs you want to run there and != to master for jobs to run ahead of merging.
You could try removing rules and build up u til you get the right order of things n
